# как удалять перенесенный уже блок Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Добрый вечер, есть функция которая позволяет перемещать с одного блока в другой. Нужна помощь в реализации того чтоб можно было те блоки которые перенесены удалять при клике на допустим крестик в углу.
Это HTML

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="drag-object" ng-repeat="obj in draggableObjects" ng-if="obj.allowClone !== false">
      {{obj.name}}
      <div ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="drag-object"  style="background-color: transparent; overflow: visible">
      <div ng-drag="true" class="drag-object" ng-drag-data="draggableObjects[3]">{{draggableObjects[3].name}}</div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete1($data,$event)">
      <span class="title">Drop area #1</span>
      <div ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects1" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj" ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess1($data,$event)">
          {{obj.name}}
      </div>
  </div>
```

Вот собственно Angular

```
angular.module('ExampleApp', ['ngDraggable']).
  controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.draggableObjects = [{name:'one'}, {name:'two'}, {name:'three'}, {name:'no-clone', allowClone:false}];
    $scope.droppedObjects1 = [];
    $scope.droppedObjects2= [];
    $scope.onDropComplete1=function(data,evt){
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects1.indexOf(data);
        if (index == -1)
        $scope.droppedObjects1.push(data);
    }
    $scope.onDragSuccess1=function(data,evt){
        var index = $scope.droppedObjects1.indexOf(data);
        if (index > -1) {
            $scope.droppedObjects1.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
    var inArray = function(array, obj) {
        var index = array.indexOf(obj);
    }
```

и есть ли какая-то реализация того чтоб когда блок перенесен допустим не один а несколько, между ними соединялась стрелка?
Буду очень признателен за помощь. Просто только осваиваю Angular зеленый еще)

Comment: Я так понимаю нужна функция, которая будет отрабатывать по событию ng-click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects1" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj" ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess1($data,$event)" ng-click="removeItem(obj)">
```

js

```
$scope.removeItem = function(item) {
    var index = $scope.droppedObjects1.indexOf(item);

    if (index > -1) {
        $scope.droppedObjects1.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Зеленую стрелку наврятле найдете готовую.

Comment: Спасибо, помог - но блоки удаляются только после того как в области видимости появляется более одного, если он там один, удалить его нельзя.

Comment: Должен работать, выложите пример на проблемой http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue

Comment: @ОлегНормпасан как минимум сначала надо подключать библиотеки, а потом свой код, который использует библиотеки. Посмотрите ошибки в консоли

Comment: Вот все сделал, http://plnkr.co/edit/pgclq7FvafgmJPo4Lmqn?p=preview Но не удаляеться первый Элемент

Comment: Также заметил непонятное поведение , когда кликаешь дважды на блок который перетащил уже, он клонируется.

Comment: Вопрос решен, удалив значение из front части ng-drag="true"